# What's difference between crossorigin anonymous and use-credentials

Tags: cors

from MDN

anonymous

> A cross-origin request (i.e., with Origin: HTTP header) is performed. But no credential is sent (i.e., no cookie, no X.509 certificate, and no HTTP Basic authentication is sent). If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (by not setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted.

use-credentials

> A cross-origin request (i.e., with Origin: HTTP header) performed with credential is sent (i.e., a cookie, a certificate, and HTTP Basic authentication is performed). If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (through Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted.

but, what's the usage difference between them.

Answer (score 4):

`anonymous` and `use-credentials` are attribute values which translate into requesting a resource with `same-origin` and `include` respectively.

When requesting a resource without specifying the `crossorigin` attribute (i.e. omitted), then you will make a no-CORS fetch. This should be used for resources which aren't protected by CORS.

When requesting a resource using `crossorigin="anonymous"` (or `crossorigin=""` as this is the default value) then you are switching it to a CORS request. This means that a resource protected by CORS (example: `fetch()`) would be sent to the browser if the response headers include

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Note we are using the `*` wildcard, but this could be a also be specific origin.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
```

When requesting a resource using `crossorigin="use-credentials"` then you are making a request for a resource which is protected by CORS and may also include private data, for example your banking information (for example: `fetch("https://bank.com/my-transaction-history/")`). In such cases, the response header should include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Vary: Cookie, Origin
```

The server receiving the request will have access to cookies, the `Authorization` header, client certificates to be able to authenticate the user and also the ability to set a cookie on the browser making the request using the `Set-Cookie`

Read more: https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that credentials are sent for requests from that element. Servers can require credentials in order to approve the request.